# C# - TreeView - Data Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, treeview, tree-traversal

I work with C# WPF TreeView.

I have folowing input data: (like 1000+ lines that I need to process)

```
\Folder\Base\Data\dat.cfg
\Folder\Base\Data1\dat.cfg
\Folder\dat.cfg
```

Collection class - **TreeItem**. Used for TreView binding.

```
    public class TreeItem : MyViewModel
    {
        public TreeItem()
        {
            this.Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm spending on this fews days and I'm not able to figure out algorithm how to obtain data to requested point.

Please I would really appreciate if somebody could give me help or just way how to achieve it.

Thank you in advance.

This is my class for collection

I need to acomplish input data to be parsed as following in my defined collection class - TreeItem.
Basicaly just to be working in TreeView as nodes with levels.

[Requested data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u59EI.png)

```
CollectionTreeItem
[0] Name - "Folder"
    Children
    [0] Name - "Base"
        Children 
            [0] Name - "Data"
            Children 
                [0] Name - "dat.cfg"
                Children
```

Only example with procesed line - \Folder\Base\Data\dat.cfg. Of course there will be more child with another lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive algorithm to build the tree. `treeObjects` should hold the structure you're trying to achieve.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] paths = new string[]
        {
            @"\Folder\Base\Data\dat.cfg",
            @"\Folder\Base\Data1\dat.cfg",
            @"\Folder\dat.cfg"
            // Rest of your paths
        };

        var root = new TreeItem { Name = "Root" };

        BuildTree(root, paths);

        var treeObjects = GetTreeObjects(root);
    }

    static void BuildTree(TreeItem root, string[] paths)
    {
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            AddPathToTree(root, path.Split('\\').Skip(1).ToArray());
        }
    }

    static void AddPathToTree(TreeItem root, string[] path)
    {
        TreeItem currentNode = root;

        foreach (var folder in path)
        {
            var existingNode = currentNode.Children.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == folder);

            if (existingNode == null)
            {
                var newNode = new TreeItem { Name = folder };
                currentNode.Children.Add(newNode);
                currentNode = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                currentNode = existingNode;
            }
        }
    }

    static List<CollectionTreeItem> GetTreeObjects(TreeItem node)
    {
        var result = new List<CollectionTreeItem>
        {
            new CollectionTreeItem
            {
                Name = node.Name,
                Children = GetChildrenObjects(node.Children)
            }
        };

        return result;
    }

    static List<CollectionTreeItem> GetChildrenObjects(ObservableCollection<TreeItem> children)
    {
        var result = new List<CollectionTreeItem>();

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            var childObject = new CollectionTreeItem
            {
                Name = child.Name,
                Children = GetTreeObjects(child)
            };

            result.Add(childObject);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class CollectionTreeItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CollectionTreeItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your effort on this topic. I had to do little adjustment but works well for me.